# OpenSSL error with RVM rubies on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby, openssl, rvm, ubuntu-12.04

I'm having persistent issues with OpenSSL on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine. I'm using RVM, and I've tried [the official solutions](https://rvm.io/packages/openssl/), to no avail.

Requests made to *some* hosts fail (for instance, `bitbucket.org`) with SSL fail. For instance, Mechanize throws this:

`OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
                                                                                                                       from /home/avo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/net-http-persistent-2.7/`

Anybody have any hints?

Answer (score 0):

the issue got solved on irc #rvm - the domain name https://bitbucket.org vs. https://bitbucket.com - the second one does not have proper certificate.